# Haskell - Why can't I map into a sorted and grouped list of lists?

Tags: haskell

I have a function:

```
listLengths :: [Int] -> [Int]
listLengths xs = map length sort(group(xs))
```

The `sort` and `group` work so when I input say `[1,3,5,5,3]` it separates and sorts it into `[[1],[3,3],[5,5]]`. However when I add `map length` as above it should then say `[1,2,2]` (the lengths of each of those lists but all I seem to get are type errors.

Comment: Are you sure you want `sort (group xs)` and not `group (sort xs)`?

Comment: map length.group.sort $ [1,3,5,5,3] ... ... ... ... ... [1,2,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in Haskell function calls are done like `f x`, not `f (x)`. Sure in many cases `f (x)` will work as well, but here you have basically written:

```
listLengths xs = map length sort (group(xs))
```

or more verbose:

```
listLengths xs = ((map length) sort) (group(xs))
```

Haskell thus sees `sort` as an independent parameter, and `group (xs)` as an extra one. But since `sort` is a function, and not a list, the typechecker will raise an error.

You can write it like:

```
listLengths :: [Int] -> [Int]
listLengths xs = map length (sort (group xs))
```

We here thus use brackets to specify that `sort (group xs)` is a parameter, the parameter in a function application with the function `map length :: [[a]] -> [Int]`.

Alternatively, we can use a point-free way like:

```
listLengths :: [Int] -> [Int]
listLengths = map length . sort . group
```

Here we make use of the `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` function to "chain" functions together. Notice that we do not have an `xs` parameter here. We thus construct a new function that first applies `group` to the input, then the output of this function is passed to the `sort` function, and finally the output of this function application is passed to the `map length` function.

This will produce the output:

```
Prelude Data.List> listLengths xs = map length (sort (group xs))
Prelude Data.List> listLengths [1,3,5,5,3]
[1,1,1,2]
```

which is not completely what you want. This is because now we construct as groups: `[[1], [3], [5,5], [3]]` and then we sort these like `[[1], [3], [3], [5, 5]]` and then it will result in `[1, 1, 1, 2]` when we calculate the `length` of each subelement.

What you thus probably want is:

```
listLengths :: [Int] -> [Int]
listLengths = map length . group . sort
```